# Chapter A to Appedix A in Latex

Tags: latex

How do I change my Appendix headings from Chapter A to Appendix A?

I am using :

```
 \begin{appendices}
 \input{Appendix.tex}
 \end{appendices}
```

Inside the input file, every appendix starts with

```
  \chapter{}
```

In the table of content it displays correctly

Appendix A
Appendix B... and so on,

But in the heading of the chapter it appears Chapter A.

Comment: Does this answer your question? http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21047/how-to-change-appendix-chapter-name

Comment: I can't replicate your problem. Can you provide us with a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/5764) that replicates the problem?